# How to fix Failed to invoke private with no args

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, coroutine

I can not understand why this error appeared and how to fix it. help me please

> Failed to invoke private ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd() with
> no args

I looked at the structure of the transmitted data in retrofit2 but did not see any errors

```
@Keep
interface PrintApi {

    @GET
    suspend fun getPrintCommands(@Url url: String, @Query("bib") bib: Int?, @Query("card") card: String): PrintResponse
   //  fun getPrintCommands(@Url url: String, @Query("bib") bib: Int?, @Query("card") card: String): Single<PrintResponse>
}


@Keep
@Serializable
data class PrintResponse(
    val ok: Boolean? = false,
    val error: String = readLine() ?: "", //test
    val printout: List<PrintCmd>? = null
)

@Keep
@Serializable
sealed class PrintCmd()

@Keep
@Serializable
@SerialName("formatted_text")
data class PrintFormatterTextCmd(
    val content: String,
    val left_margin: Float,
    val letter_width: Float,
    val line_height: Float,
    val font_family: String,
    val font_size: Int,
    val align: String,
    val bold: Boolean,
    val italic: Boolean,
    val underline: Boolean
) : PrintCmd()
```

then the call itself

```
@Singleton
class PrintService @Inject constructor(
    private val printManager: PrinterManager,
    @AppScope coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val api: PrintApi,
    private val eventRepository: EventRepository
) : CoroutineScope by coroutineScope {

    fun print(dao: TagDao, id: Long?, bib: Int?, tagNumber: String = "") = eventRepository.urls.withLatestValue {
        val url = it?.printUrl
        launch {
            try {
                val result = print(url, bib, tagNumber)
                if (id != null) {
                    dao.setPrintStatus(id, if (result) Status.Done else Status.Error)
                }
            }
            catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("TEST", e.toString())

            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun print(url: String?, bib: Int?, tagNumber: String = ""): Boolean {
        if (url.isNullOrBlank()) {
            return false
        }
        val commands = getCommands(url, bib, tagNumber)
        return commands?.let {
            printManager.printAll(it)
            true
        } ?: false
    }

     private suspend fun getCommands(url: String, bib: Int?, tagNumber: String): List<PrintCmd>? {
    
            try {
                val result = api.getPrintCommands(url, bib, tagNumber)
    
    /**/
                if (result.ok == true && result.error.isBlank()  && result.printout != null ||
                    result.ok == true && result.error == "EVENT_NOT_EDITABLE"  && result.printout != null)
                {
                return result.printout
                }
                else
                {
                    return null
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e("TEST", e.message())
                Logger.w(e)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("TEST", e.toString())
                Logger.w(e)
            }
            return null /**/
        } /**/
```

I tried to change the PrtintCmd structure, but it did not bring me success
I do not even understand what this error can be connected with. It appeared after changing the library
`implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0")`
to the next library
`implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"`

and after replacing the code in this section

```
 .addConverterFactory(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
```

to the following code in this section

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

please help me figure it out

Stack trace:

> W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private
> ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd() with no args W/System.err:
> at
> com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
> W/System.err:     at
> retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
> W/System.err:     at
> retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
> W/System.err:     at
> retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243) W/System.err:
> at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
> W/System.err:     at
> okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't
> instantiate abstract class ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native
> Method) W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
> W/System.err:     ... 14 more

Comment: Please share some details about the Error, also the stack trace.

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee I'm not very good at catching errors in coroutines. In the logs, apart from this line of error, there is nothing else, unfortunately, if you help me, I will provide all the details

Comment: In the catch block try to print the stack trace like this: `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee added logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hej Ethernets,

I think the error is that you are trying to instantiate a sealed class:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd W/System.err: at
```

In your PrintResponse, you are expecting a List of PrintCmd so the converter tries to parse the response to this class, but a `sealed class` cannot be instantiated. I think you have to change the type to the implementation:

```
data class PrintResponse(
    val ok: Boolean? = false,
    val error: String = readLine() ?: "", //test
    val printout: List<PrintFormatterTextCmd>? = null
)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much bin looking at solutions for 4 hours now